# Reading from a text file and Matching user input to certain field columns in the text file. Columns are delimited

Tags: java, menu, io, delimiter

I'm creating a menu based console application using Java. I have a class that allows the user to sign up by inputting their information. This information is written to a file that is appended each time a new user is entered.

I would like to have a login function, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to read the file and only match the user input to the first two columns `ID;Password`.

Once they match the user input, I'll be able to continue to the next menu.
My text file looks like this:

```
ID;Password;FirstName;LastName;Email
admin;1234;adminFirst;adminLast;adminMail@admin.com
```

Here's my Login class as well. I created an array for user input, just in case that would be useful:

```
public class Log_In extends Main_Menu {

    public void logging_in(){

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter your login information!");

        String [] log_in_array = new String[2];

        String ID, password;

        System.out.print("ID: ");
        ID = in.next();

        System.out.print("Password: ");
        password = in.next();

        //Stores the ID and PASSWORD to the array. Now we will compare the array to the txt file to find a match
        //Must match FIELD_ONE;FIELD_TWO
        log_in_array [0] = ID;
        log_in_array [1] = password;


        in.close();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can write helper method to read your text file and compare id and password provided by user, like following.

```
// The name of the file to open.
static String fileName = "myTextFliel.txt";

public static boolean myHelper(String id, String password) {
    // This will reference one line at a time
    String line = null;
    boolean retVal= false;
    try {
        // FileReader reads text files in the default encoding.
        FileReader fileReader = 
            new FileReader(fileName);

        // Always wrap FileReader in BufferedReader.
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = 
            new BufferedReader(fileReader);

        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            //create a token based on 
            String [] token=line.split(";");
            // because you know first and second word of each line in 
            // given file is id and password 
            if (token[0].equals(id) && token[1].equals(password)){
                retVal=true;
                return retVal;
            }
        }   

        // Always close files.
        bufferedReader.close();         
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println(
            "Unable to open file '" + 
            fileName + "'");                
    }
    catch(IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(
            "Error reading file '" 
            + fileName + "'");                  
        // Or we could just do this: 
        // ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return retVal;
}


public void logging_in(){

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter your login information!");

    String [] log_in_array = new String[2];

    String ID, password;

    System.out.print("ID: ");
    ID = in.next();

    System.out.print("Password: ");
    password = in.next();

    //Stores the ID and PASSWORD to the array. Now we will compare the array to the txt file to find a match
    //Must match FIELD_ONE;FIELD_TWO
    log_in_array [0] = ID;
    log_in_array [1] = password;


    // Here you can call your helper method. 
    boolean foundMe =myHelper(log_in_array [0],log_in_array [1])
    if (foundMe==true){
     //do whatever u want to do
    }

    in.close();

}
```

With little bit of more work you can ignore header line.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'll implement this in the morning. It's pretty late, and I have work in the morning.

Comment: No problem. If u like this answer, u can vote and accept the answer if u was looking something like this

Comment: It worked! There was a slight mistake though. I just had to change the token array to `if (token[0].equals(id) && token[1].equals(password)){` because it was technically only reading the first word. Hopefully it still works as I add more information to the txt file. Appreciate the help!

Comment: Glad i could help. you can accept this answer if it worked. can click to the arrow in starting of my answer(left hand side) and make it green.

Answer (score 0):

If the structure of the file is something like this

```
username pass data data
username pass data data
username pass data data... and so on
```

you can read the file into an ArrayList, but skip everything that isn't a user name or pass like so

```
ArrayList<String> userinfo = new ArrayList();
while (input.hasNext()){ //input is a Scanner object that is your file
    userinfo.add(input.next());//username
    userinfo.add(input.next());//pass
    input.next();//skip
    input.next();//skip
}
```

every username and password will be in pairs like this within the

```
ArrayList
(username, pass, username, pass, username, pass,...)
```

Then to see if a username and password matches

```
int index = userinfo.indexOf(ID);
if (userinfo.get(index+1).equals(password))//the password comes right after the username in the list
    return true;
```

I'm assuming this is for practice, you would typically use a database of some sort for user name and passwords

Comment: Yes, I'm a beginner, so this is practice. I understood your suggestion, and I added it to my program. I am getting an error stating that : 

`Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException`

It has something to do with: `userinfo.add(input.next());//pass`

Thanks for the help btw!